# I have to fix a bug nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, wallpaper

I have an error that only appears in froyo devices

nullpointerexception in Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:344)
at com.varxstudio.beautifulwallpapersLite.Imagen.a(Unknown Source)
at com.varxstudio.beautifulwallpapersLite.g.a(Unknown Source)
at com.varxstudio.beautifulwallpapersLite.g.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

and here is the code any solution?? why only in froyo??? 
previously only used BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream) to load images but I found a flusedInputStream method to do this but I still get the same error

```
private class DownloadDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog myDialog = null;
    int result = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Imagen.this, "", advert);
        myDialog.setCancelable(true);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        result = setWallpaper(path);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        myDialog.dismiss();
        switch (result){
            ----
        }
        return;
    }
}

public int setWallpaper(String path) {          
    int width, height;
    Bitmap dbm, bm;         
    bm = null;
    dbm = null; 
    InputStream is = null;

    WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    dis = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();           

    if((wpm != null) && (dis != null)){ 
        height = dis.getHeight();
        width = (int) (height * 1.33);              

        try {           
            URLConnection conn = new URL(path).openConnection();                
            conn.connect();             
            is = conn.getInputStream();             

            if (is != null) {                   
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));                    
                dbm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, false);
                wpm.setBitmap(dbm);                 
            }else {
                return 2;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {                 
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } finally {             
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }           
        if(bm != null){
            bm.recycle();
        }
        if(dbm != null){
            dbm.recycle();  
        }           
    }else {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break;  // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `bm` null? `decodeStream` returns null if the image could not be processed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the NullPointerException because 
 `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));` returns null,   Reasons why `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)` returns null is because of the bad image..
Bad Image in the sense make sure that your are returning the bitmap format supported by Android,(Example `Android doesn't support tiff`). And the second reason is because of the image Resolution, if the image resolution is too high that decoding fails..so make sure that you've small image.

This is the question I have posted in the SO regarding the same..[Bitmap failed to create using BitmapFactory.decodeArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681643/image-isnt-creating-using-the-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray)

I have faced the same problem earlier but I have over come it by using the tutorial provided by Android developers site  [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)