# Error in Base64 string To image

Tags: android

android code Error :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(""aHR0cHM6Ly9ldGlja2V0LmlwZWt0ci5jb20vd3Nib3MzL0xvZ29WZXIuQXNweD9mbnVtPTI2NQ=="", Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap base64Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                    decodedString.length);
Log.d("img", String.valueOf(base64Bitmap));
imagview.setImageBitmap(base64Bitmap);
```

logcat Message

```
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681643/image-isnt-creating-using-the-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray

Comment: Load using Picasso.with(context).load("i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView); by adding dependency in project. If you need to do so and required more info  revert me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    try {
        url = decodeBase64String(base64String);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView);
String decodeBase64String(String encodedString) throws   UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return new String(data, "UTF-8");
}
```

set dependency  -compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

Answer (score 2):

Your base64 string is corrupted.

Check it via below link:

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Please try to decode some different string and then check it.

or try below code :

```
 byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode("aHR0cHM6Ly9ldGlja2V0LmlwZWt0ci5jb20vd3Nib3MzL0xvZ29WZXIuQXNweD9mbnVtPTI2NQ", Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                    encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
```

If still it won't work try  Base64.NOWRAP instead of Base64.DEFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

Check this function:

```
    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```